# LTE Cat M1 vs NB-IoT : Building penetration

Tags: wireless

I browsed a lot search engines results to find any information (at "noob" level) about building penetration of these technologies.

For my IoT project, I'm now using LTE Cat.4 as I didn't know before about Cat M1 and NB-IoT. I'm facing a lot of issues because my systems are often installed underground (building basements). Since I don't need Cat.4 UL/DL speeds, I'm looking for better alternatives.

How better is the waves building penetration compared to LTE Cat.4 for LTE Cat M1 and NB-IoT + Cat M1 compared to NB-IoT ? From my searches on Internet, I know NB-IoT will be the best but the very low UL/DL speeds and the high latency may be a problem. Although I don't use applications with strict real-time needs, I should be able to synchronize the user data under (a few KB) under a reasonable delay as well to perform updates of some packages (< 1MB).

Comment: Usually Cat M1 and NB IoT are placed in the lower frequency bands (700-800 MHz.)  and will have far better building penetration than signal in the 1700, 1900, 2100 and 2600MHz bands.

Comment: It really depends on your deployment, though!

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help Peter and Marcus.
I will buy a NB-IoT/LTE Cat. M1 module and check the difference !

Comment: @Carton_ You need to make sure that the operator in your area supports NB-IoT.  We are testing NB-IoT for a product right now, and we had to apply the cellular company to get into a test program in order to get sim cards for the NB IoT devices. At first we tried with a regular sim card and got thrown off the network immediately. :-(

Comment: I've written an e-mail to my operator. They support both Cat. M1 and NB-IoT. For Cat. M1, I can use it with my actual subscription but for NB-IoT I need another option. So it's good news.
I will try Cat. M1 first and, if needed, I will call my operator to activate the NB-IoT option and try it too